# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utcnow'

Tags: python, datetime

When I input the simple code:

```
import datetime
datetime.utcnow()
```

, I was given error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.utcnow()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utcnow'
```

But python's document of `utcnow` is just here: https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow. Why does `utcnow` not work in my computer? Thank you!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You are confusing the module with the type.

Use either:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

or use:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.utcnow()
```

e.g. either reference the `datetime` type in the `datetime` module, or import that type into your namespace from the module. If you use the latter form and need *other* types from that module, don't forget to import those too:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
```

Demo of the first form:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime
<module 'datetime' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so'>
>>> datetime.datetime
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 4, 23, 27, 14, 678151)
```

Comment: I've had a couple of occasions in complex systems, where the datetime module somehow gets trampled and datetime.utcnow() fails as datetime is None. It's not relevant to the original question but it can sometimes be an indicator of a bigger problem in large systems.

Comment: @MikeStoddart: that'd be a different problem. Perhaps you have something running when the Python interpreter is exiting; at that point globals are being set to `None` throughout, and you'll see exactly that type of issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I think it was caused by circular imports.

Comment: @MikeStoddart: That would usually give a different error; an `AttributeError`, usually, but not for the module object, not `None`.

Comment: Note that the last import statement overrules the previous one. So even if you use 'from datetime import datetime' and one of the next imports, import datetime with 'import datetime' it will be imported as a module and the attribute error will still occur.

Comment: @Lorenz: yes, because both the type and the module are *just objects*, referenced by names in your module. `import` binds to a name in the current namespace, there is nothing special about those names from using `datetime = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that, **the method "utcnow" in class "datetime" is now deprecated** and will be removed in a future version.

You can use the following instead:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

Source [Python 3.12 release note](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html).